# How to slice and recombine text based on nested tags with Beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

In the following html I need to read all the text in order and also combine separate sentences for each span class.

```
<label for="01">"The traveler, with his powerful "
    <span class ="Wizard">"Storm"</span>
    <span class ="Warrior">"Whirlwind"</span>
    <span class ="Monk">"Prayer"</span>", took down the dark forces of evil. The "
    <span class ="Wizard">"wizard"</span>
    <span class ="Warrior">"warrior"</span>
    <span class ="Monk">"monk"</span>" was exhausted afterwards and needed to take a rest."
</label>
```

In this case there should be 3 separate sentences and the appropriate class with it in a list of lists - so the output would look like this:

```
[['Wizard', 'The traveler, with his powerful Storm, took down the dark forces of evil. The wizard was exhausted afterwards and needed to take a rest.']
['Warrior', 'The traveler, with his powerful Whirlwind, took down the dark forces of evil. The warrior was exhausted afterwards and needed to take a rest.']
['Monk', 'The traveler, with his powerful Prayer, took down the dark forces of evil. The monk was exhausted afterwards and needed to take a rest.']]
```

I have no idea how to approach this and I wasn't able to find anything on the web - probably because I am not sure how to formulate my question (if you have a suggestion how to better formulate my question please leave a comment and I will).

Thank you in advance!

edit: I tried with `find(text=True)` and `find_all(text=True)` but I wasn't able to figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby`

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from itertools import groupby
d = [(a, list(b)) for a, b in groupby(list(filter(lambda x:x != '\n', soup(content, 'html.parser').label.contents)), key=lambda x:isinstance(x, bs4.element.NavigableString))]
users, _text = list(zip(*[b for a, b in d if not a])), [b for a, b in d if a]
result = [[a[0]['class'][0], (lambda x:''.join(f'{j[1:-1]} {next(x).text[1:-1]}' if l < len(_text) - 1 else j[1:-2] for l, [j] in enumerate(_text)))(iter(a))] for a in users]
```

There are some additional `\n` characters in the output, you can remove them with `re`:

```
import re
final_result = [[a, re.sub('"\n\s+', '', b)] for a, b in result]
```

Output:

```
[['Wizard', 'The traveler, with his powerful Storm, took down the dark forces of evil. The wizard was exhausted afterwards and needed to take a rest.'], 
 ['Warrior', 'The traveler, with his powerful Whirlwind, took down the dark forces of evil. The warrior was exhausted afterwards and needed to take a rest.'], 
 ['Monk', 'The traveler, with his powerful Prayer, took down the dark forces of evil. The monk was exhausted afterwards and needed to take a rest.']]
```

Comment: Is this the full code? I am not able to successfully run it  - i get an error at bs4.element "AttributeError: type object 'BeautifulSoup' has no attribute 'element'"

Comment: In my previous comment I have probably forgot to include import bs4 - I will try it out and see how it works in 5mins